# How to remove scheme from url in Python?

Tags: python, url-rewriting

I am working with an application that returns urls, written with `Flask`. I want the `URL` displayed to the user to be as clean as possible so I want to remove the `http://` from it. I looked and found the `urlparse` library, but couldn't find any examples of how to do this.

What would be the best way to go about it, and if `urlparse` is overkill is there a simpler way? Would simply removing the "`http://`" substring from the URL just using the regular string parsing tools be bad practice or cause problems?

Answer (score 13):

I don't think `urlparse` offers a single method or function for this. This is how I'd do it:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

url = 'HtTp://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=2'

def strip_scheme(url):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    scheme = "%s://" % parsed.scheme
    return parsed.geturl().replace(scheme, '', 1)

print strip_scheme(url)
```

Output:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=2
```

If you'd use (only) simple string parsing, you'd have to deal with `http[s]`, and possibly other schemes yourself. Also, this handles weird casing of the scheme.

Comment: For Python 3 the imports are from urllib.parse import urlparse

Answer (score 8):

If you are using these programmatically rather than using a replace, I suggest having urlparse recreate the url without a scheme.

The ParseResult object is a tuple. So you can create another removing the fields you don't want.

```
# py2/3 compatibility
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, ParseResult
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse, ParseResult


def strip_scheme(url):
    parsed_result = urlparse(url)
    return ParseResult('', *parsed_result[1:]).geturl()
```

You can remove any component of the parsedresult by simply replacing the input with an empty string.

It's important to note there is a functional difference between this answer and @Lukas Graf's answer. The most likely functional difference is that the '//' component of a url isn't technically the scheme, so this answer will preserve it, whereas it will remain here.

```
>>> Lukas_strip_scheme('https://yoman/hi?whatup')
'yoman/hi?whatup'
>>> strip_scheme('https://yoman/hi?whatup')
'//yoman/hi?whatup'
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple regex search and replace works.

```
import re
def strip_scheme(url: str):
    return re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/', '', url)
```

Comment: Those escape characters are redundant in Python's regex engine. `re.sub(r'^https?://', '', url)` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this done in Flask libraries and extensions. Worth noting you can do it **although** it does make use of a protected member (._replace) of the ParseResult/SplitResult.

```
url = 'HtTp://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=2'
split_url = urlsplit(url) 
# >>> SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='stackoverflow.com', path='/questions/tagged/python', query='page=2', fragment='')
split_url_without_scheme = split_url._replace(scheme="")
# >>> SplitResult(scheme='', netloc='stackoverflow.com', path='/questions/tagged/python', query='page=2', fragment='')
new_url = urlunsplit(split_url_without_scheme)
```

Comment: The `_replace` method is not protected. It is meant to be a public part of the API. It only has the underscore to prevent name collisions. The three methods and two attributes listed here are all public: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple. Named tuples disallow field names starting with `_` so that the standard lib can use the underscore as a pseudo-namespace.

Comment: This does not work as the resulting url starts with `//`

Comment: @theannouncer that is true. One would have to strip that out as well but then we'd end up with something more closely resembling the answer from Lukas Graf, which is more elegant

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing) the return value is a named tuple, its items can be accessed by index or as named attributes. So we can get access to certain parts of parsed url by using named attributes:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def delete_http(link):
    url = urlparse(link)
    return url.netloc + url.path

user_link = input()
print(delete_http(user_link))
```

Input: https://stackoverflow.com/
Output: stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That doesn't strip scheme from the url but rather returns domain+path. Url might have query params and fragments you'd remove here too.

Answer (score 0):

Almost 9 years since the question was asked and still not much have changed :D.
This is the cleanest way I came up with to solve that issue:

```
def strip_scheme(url: str) -> str:
    schemaless = urlparse(url)._replace(scheme='').geturl()
    return schemaless[2:] if schemaless.startswith("//") else schemaless
```

And some unit tests:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ['url', 'expected_url'],
    [
        #  Test url not changed when no scheme
        ('www.test-url.com', 'www.test-url.com'),
        #  Test https scheme stripped
        ('https://www.test-url.com', 'www.test-url.com'),
        #  Test http scheme stripped
        ('http://www.test-url.com', 'www.test-url.com'),
        #  Test only scheme stripped when url with path
        ('https://www.test-url.com/de/fr', 'www.test-url.com/de/fr'),
        #  Test only scheme stripped when url with path and params
        ('https://test.com/de/fr?param1=foo', 'test.com/de/fr?param1=foo'),
    ]
)
def test_strip_scheme(url: str, expected_url: str) -> None:
    assert strip_scheme(url) == expected_url
```