# Fastest way to convert a URI into a scheme relative URI (in python)

Tags: python

In python, whats the *fastest* way to convert a url of the type `scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment` into a "scheme relative" or "protocol relative" URI?

---

Currently, I'm doing a version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21687728/4936905), but was thinking there might be a more concise/faster way to accomplish this. The input always has `https://` or `http://` appended to it.

Comment: you're doing a version of that answer....can you show your code so we know what version/how you are implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way that I could find is with `str.partition`:

```
In [1]: url = 'https://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment'

In [2]: %timeit url.partition('://')[2]
The slowest run took 6.70 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 251 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit url.split('://', 1)[1]
The slowest run took 5.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 407 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit url.replace('http', '', 1).replace('s://', '', 1)
The slowest run took 4.24 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 589 ns per loop
```

Since all you're doing is stripping off text ending in a fixed string, there doesn't seem to be much benefit in parsing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urlparse import urlparse
o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')

print o.scheme
print o.netloc
print o.path
```

is how i would probably do it ...

Comment: Wouldn't that get rid of `scheme` and `netloc` both?