# How to filter input data into database in Django models

Tags: django

I have a model like the below. No matter which url is input, I wanna remove protocols in each url such as `http://` or `https://` before it is stored into database. Is there any filtering feature for that?

```
class Store(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `save` method in order to manipulate any model fields before they are stored in the database. For example:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = self.url.split('//')[-1]
        super(Store, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21687728/2011147) for a more compliant method of removing the scheme (http or https part) from any URL.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to remove the protocol and then save it on the model.

```
import re
from .models import Store

address_before_cleaning = "https://www.google.com"
address_after_cleaning = re.sub('[\d\w]+://', '', address_before_cleaning)
store_object = Store()
store_object.url = address_after_cleaning
store_object.save()
```

There is documentations for re in [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)